# ReplaceAll causing infinite recursion

Tags: replacement

I have two expressions

```
expressionA = (-B*a + b)/M
expressionB = (-A*c + d)/M
```

`expressionA` depends on `B` and vice versa. What I would like to do is replace `B` in `expressionA` with `expressionB`.

I tried doing this by using the ReplaceAll operator `/.` which works, but only if I don't assign the result to a new variable, i.e

```
expressionA /. B -> expressionB
expressionB /. A -> expressionA
```

gives the expected outputs:

```
(b - (a (-A c + d))/M)/M
(d - ((b - a B) c)/M)/M
```

However, if I now want to define a new variable as

```
A = expressionA /. B -> expressionB
```

I get the following error:

$RecursionLimit: "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of `b-(a(-Ac+d))/M`".

This happens not only if I try to define `A` as above but also if copy paste the correct output, i.e. if I try

```
A=(b - (a (-A c + d))/M)/M
```

I get the same error as above.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem or if there is an alternative way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What is your goal? What is wrong with the first approach? What do you need to do next? You do understand why you're getting the error message, don't you?

Comment: My goal is to replace B in expressionA with expressionB. The problem is that I need these expressions with the replacements later on and whenever I try to do something with the results I get the error message. Also, I do not understand why I get the error message. This is actually my first project with Mathematica so I might be missing something trivial...

Comment: Regarding the error... evaluate this `x = x + 1`. Formally, there's no problem here. We even get `OwnValues` (`OwnValues[x]` gives `{HoldPattern[x]:>1+x}`). However, when we now want to evaluate `x+1`, we must first figure out how to replace `x`, which is simple enough and gives us `x+1+1`, but now we need to replace x, which is still simple: `x+1+1+1`, but now we need to replace x...you see where this is going.

Comment: "My goal is to replace B in expressionA with expressionB." I was afraid you would say this. Yes, I understand that's how you communicated your goal, but I'm asking for some more context. You already figured out one way to achieve that specific goal, but you weren't satisfied for some reason. So, before I wanted to propose a solution, I wanted to understand where this whole thing was headed. You might need some sort of `Hold` or `HoldForm`. You might want a `Template` of some sort. You might want to use `Rule` instead of `Set`. Maybe you need `Equals` instead of `Set`.

Comment: At this point, all I can tell you is that a recursive definition with `Set` isn't going to work.

Comment: @lericr I think I know what my problem was now. What I forgot to mention was that expressionA is basically A in disguise. I was always going to end up with an infinitely recursive expression because I have something like "A depends on B which depends on A" and so on. But I can neglect anything that is of order 1/M^3 because M is very large and I thought Mathematica would not immediatly try to recursively insert A over and over again but it makes sense I guess. Do you have an idea how it could be implemented that only one recursion is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

You can never [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) a variable to an expression that contains that variable. This would always produce an infinite recursion. Instead, modify the meanings of `expressionA` and `expressionB`

```
eqns = {
   expressionA == (-B*a + b)/M,
   expressionB == (-A*c + d)/M};

rules = Thread[{A, B} -> eqns[[All, 2]]]

{A -> (b - a B)/M, B -> (-A c + d)/M}

(eqns /. rules)

{expressionA == (b - (a (-A c + d))/M)/M, 
 expressionB == (d - ((b - a B) c)/M)/M}
```

Iterating the replacements:

```
NestList[# /. rules &, eqns, 3] // Column
```

[image]